# How to find the UI view of this system alert?

Tags: ios, xcode8, kif, kif-framework

Xcode 8.2
KIF testing

I want to automate a drawing app which require permission to save photo to the library.

[This is the alert I want to accept](https://i.stack.imgur.com/peAJx.png)

With KIF I gave

```
  [tester tapViewWithAccessibilityLabel:@"OK"];
```

But it says, failed to find accessibility element. 
As a solution I try to use

```
 [tester tapAccessibilityElement:@"OK" inView:(UIView *)];
```

How can I find the UIView of this system alert?
Are there any other ways to tap this element?

Answer (score 0):

Permissions alerts are out-of-process, meaning KIF can't find them by searching through the views in the app.

There's a special function [`[tester acknowledgeSystemAlert]`](https://github.com/kif-framework/KIF/blob/40ba5e1b0fc31320e190bacd1a94199548b3f85b/Classes/KIFUITestActor.h#L560) that taps "OK" on these alerts.